# I am having conflict issues between Google Plus and Youtube Data API?

Tags: javascript, youtube, google-plus

So I have a site I'm working on which includes searching for videos using Google's YouTube Data API v3 (I am using the javascript library). Everything works fine prior to including new code on the same page importing Google+'s code to use it's share functionality. Now whenever I load the page, neither the YouTube video searches nor sharing via Google Plus seems to work. Below is the code for YouTube's Data API client load and search:

```
function initializeGapi() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY); // client API_KEY variable for client
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', 
        function() { 
            console.log('Youtube API loaded.');
            searchYoutube(''); // searches youtube
        }
    );
}
```

This HTML tag is included in the header of the page:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=OnLoadCallback"></script>
```

So everything was working well. Now the problem is when I introduce the code below for Google Plus for it's share button feature:

```
<div id="googlepluscta"> // share button
    <button
        class="g-interactivepost"
        data-contenturl="https://plus.google.com/pages/"
        data-contentdeeplinkid="/pages"
        data-clientid="142489821045.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-prefilltext="Engage your users today, create a Google+ page for your business."
        data-calltoactionlabel="CREATE"
        data-calltoactionurl="http://plus.google.com/pages/create"
        data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
      Tell your friends
    </button>
</div>
```

Also, right before the  tag the following is included to load the Google Plus client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

I've include screenshot links as well in case they may be helpful:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/57vkp7vtv/]

[image: http://postimg.org/image/5usv18v6l/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first include you are doing, this line is what's probably breaking stuff:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=OnLoadCallback"></script>
```

It's breaking because the asynchronous include you added further down the page does the same thing except it also loads the Google+ button code at the same time and without blocking the browser from loading additional resources (this is a good thing, yay async).

Now that you only have the script getting loaded once, you should also update the asynchronous load to add the YouTube API client **after** the initial script has loaded. The following example should suffice with the code you've shared:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=initializeGapi';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Now that you have only one instance of the gapi.* values being set, you should have better luck with getting your code working.

Next, if you are getting errors from the YouTube API after using interactive posts, it's most likely happening because the Interactive Post button can update the credentials for gapi. Add the scope to your button and the youtube API permissions will be added to the updated API credentials:

```
<button
    class="g-interactivepost"
    data-contenturl="https://plus.google.com/pages/"
    data-contentdeeplinkid="/pages"
    data-clientid="142489821045.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-prefilltext="Engage your users today, create a Google+ page for your business."
    data-calltoactionlabel="CREATE"
    data-calltoactionurl="http://plus.google.com/pages/create"
    data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
  Tell your friends
</button>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I didn't realize you've commented until just now :) Removing that extra script insert at the top of the page sped things up considerably. I've also added the "initializeGapi" function as the callback to the URL mentioned above in the import script I left. However, I'm still having the same issue, the page and videos from YouTube load fine (using the YouTube Data API of course). But as soon as I log into Google Plus, then try to search again using the YouTube Data API, I still receive errors. I receive a POST response 403 "Insufficient Permission":

Comment: Hey that fixed the issue and now it works perfectly! I completely overlooked the data-scope field without even noticing. Thank you very much again for your help Class!